# How do I add Basic Authentication to Spring Boot logging.config property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I currently have a spring cloud config application pulling in environment-specific properties from a config server. However, I am now trying to add a log4j.xml file to the config repo, so I can specify different logging requirements per evironment. I've got this working locally as well, but I am having trouble accessing the log4j.xml file from the remote git repository due to a lack of Basic Authorization on the url request.

config server `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          searchPaths: '{profile}'
          #username: username
          #password: password
          #uri: https://stash.mycompany.com/scm/project/config_repo.git
          # local
          uri: file:///C:/projects/config_repo
```

`application.yml` stored in the config_repo:

```
logging:
  #config: https://stash.mycompany.com/projects/project/repos/config_repo/${spring.profiles.active:default}/log4j.xml?raw
  #username: username
  #password: password
  # local
  config: file:///C:/projects/config_repo/${spring.profiles.active:default}/log4j.xml
```

client application `bootstrap.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client-app
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      #uri: http://www.mycompany.com/repos/config-server/
      # local
      uri: http://localhost:8888/config-server
```

When the spring boot application starts up, it uses basic authentication to pull down the latest config repo, read of the properties and return them to the client. I haven't found a way to set basic authentication on the url for the logging.config property, which also needs credentials to get the contents of the file back to the client to set up the correct logging.

I can hit the following url, and get the expected log4j.xml contents back in Postman if I add a Basic Authorization header: `https://stash.mycompany.com/projects/project/repos/config_repo/dev/log4j.xml?raw`

Is there a way I can add Basic Authorization the the logging.config url request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was going about this the wrong way. Instead of requesting the file from the stash repo, I should just be requesting the file from the config server:

```
http://www.mycompany.com/config-server/default/${spring.profiles.active}/master/log4j.xml
```

The `application.yml` looks like this:

```
logging:
  config: http://www.mycompany.com/config-server/default/${spring.profiles.active}/master/log4j.xml
```

The config server can return file contents from a specified path in the repo:

> [Spring Cloud Config: Serving Plain Text](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text)